# Evaluate next value in array, if condition becomes false in macro

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

There are 3 values in array. Out of those, 1 value is not there in the column for which I'm filtering the data ("matang"). I want to know how should i make it skip if there is no result for that keyword. That means after filtering using that keyword, no results are displayed. I want to skip that keyword and move onto next element of array. I have tried On Error Resume Next. So any other option?

```
    Dim Ar() As Variant
    Ar() = Array("jumpsuit", "matang", "bikini")
    Dim i As Variant
    For Each i In Ar
    Sheets("tops").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D$1335").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="*" & i & "*", Operator:=xlAnd
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Cells.Find(What:=i, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Sheets("tops").Select
    Do
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop While ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping everything after your Autofilter in a test for no results:

`If ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1 > 0 Then`

ie:

```
Dim Ar() As Variant
Ar() = Array("jumpsuit", "matang", "bikini")
Dim i As Variant
For Each i In Ar
    Sheets("tops").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D$1335").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="*" & i & "*", Operator:=xlAnd
   If ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1 > 0 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        Cells.Find(What:=i, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        ActiveCell.Range("A1").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.End(xlUp).Select
        Sheets("tops").Select
        Do
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop While ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: can you help me once more. suppose ""Cells.Find(What:=i"" is not true, that means the element that i'm searching is not found, then it should go to the next element.

Comment: I have tried On Error Resume Next. but it's not working. Can you elaborate. Or send me exact code, the way you send me earlier

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a CountIf bit of logic in there to test if the i'th element of the array exists in the range? And then jump past the section of code that makes changes if it doesnt exist (ie = 0)? In my example, i've used the term 'skip'. So like this....

```
Dim Ar() As Variant
Ar() = Array("jumpsuit", "matang", "bikini")
Dim i As Variant
For Each i In Ar
Sheets("tops").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Select

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D$1335"), i) = 0 Then

    GoTo Skip

End If

Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D$1335").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="*" & i & "*", Operator:=xlAnd
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Cells.Find(What:=i, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Range("A1").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Sheets("tops").Select
Do
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop While ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Then just put the 'skip:' term somewhere just before the next (I cant see it in your code, is it because this is just a section of a larger sub?)

Comment: thanks..can you help me once more. suppose ""Cells.Find(What:=i"" is not true, that means the element that i'm searching is not found, then it should go to the next element.

Comment: No prob. If you add the 'Skip:' keyword after that section of code in the loop but just before the 'next' (which I cant see in your macro), then it would skip that 'Cells.Find' bit of code altogether completely (so yes).

Answer (score 0):

Make a function that check a list with the wanted values after put them in a sheet.

```
Function checking(value as string)
Dim x as integer
Dim numWantedvalues as Integer

numWantedvalues = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A"))

For x = 1 to numWantedvalues
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & x) = value Then
        checking = True
    End If
Next x
end function
```

Then introduce the function in your code:

```
If checking(arValue) = True Then
    'Actions that you want to do
End If
```

Comment: thanks.. can you help me once more. suppose ""Cells.Find(What:=i"" is not true, that means the element that i'm searching is not found, then it should go to the next element.